# Selenium python hidden element cant be clicked unless hovered over

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to create a program that will automatically host a krunker map when i run it but to host it the program has to click a button which only shows up if u hover over the map and i dont know how to do that with selenium (ps im gonna set the server to private and i dont think i can just do that with a link and i dont wanna use any code that moves the mouse like pyautogui. If there is a better way to host a pivate custom map (with password) please share.

```
driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://krunker.io')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='menuBtnHost' and contains(., 'Host Game')]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='menuWindow' and contains(., 'Custom')]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='hostCMapPickr']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bigMenTab' and contains(., 'search')]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='mapList']"))).click()
    mapname = driver.find_element(By.ID,"mpSrch")
    mapname.send_keys('Zombie_Bulwark')
    mapname.send_keys(Keys.ENTER);
                                                          <<<what must i do here to click the button?
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mapActionB']"))).click()                                       <<<button i wanna click
```

Comment: what's the xpath of the map ?

Comment: <div class="mapActionB" title="Host" onclick="selectHostMap(&quot;Zombie_Bulwark&quot;,&quot;undefined&quot;,&quot;114845&quot;,&quot;Keybi&quot;,1)"><span class="material-icons" style="font-size:70px;color:#fff;">video_settings</span></div>                                                       here is the button im trying to click

Comment: you need to hover over the map so you can click the button right?

Comment: yes, but i wanna do it in such a way that u can do it headless

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

There is a way to simulate the mousehover in selenium

You can try the following

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc # pip install undetected-chromedriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = uc.Chrome()

mapp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'put the map xpath here')
mousehover = ActionChains(driver)
mousehover.move_to_element(mapp)
mousehover.perform()

# your mouse click
# WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='mapActionB']"))).click()
```

Comment: comes back with "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. "

Comment: put the chromedriver in the same folder as your script

Comment: i would like to use 
'''
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
'''

Comment: @helpimstuck.exe I've updated the question so you can try again